# Facebook connect in codeigniter app

Tags: facebook

I am trying to create a facebook app on my local machine which will allow users to login/register on the app by using their facebook login details. I have gone through 2 tutorials and i keep getting one of 2 errors.

1.404 Page Not Found when i go localhost/app/login
2. CodeIgniter: “Unable to load the requested class” whe localhost/app/index.php/login

has anyone gone through this issue before or am i missing something.

Thnaks

Comment: How does this apply to expressionengine? Sounds like you're building a pure codeigniter project.

Comment: i was testing this using codeigniter, wanted to implement it via controllers and views in expressionengine without using any third party plugins or modules, hope I am making sense

Comment: You would be better off building a module.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tha @jim Wyse implemented the facebook sdk 5 module in the contollers and views folder. worked locally